# Slow WP Site, theme.php not caching? Up to 25 second load time!

Tags: cache, plugin-w3-total-cache, server-load, performance

I have two WP subdirectories off of a Joomla domain. The Joomla load time is ok. However, the WPs are so so sooooo slow. The back end is slow too. I have w3 cache installed on both and I've copied the settings from some great resources, but they are still slow! Could someone please take a look?

http://www.howlatthemoon.com/howl2go/

http://www.howlatthemoon.com/dueling_piano_bar/

Comment: I took a quick peek, and the sites loaded quickly for me.  Try the usual WP debugging stuff first -- disable all plugins and re-enable them one at a time, to see if one of them is causing the slowdown; try using a default WP theme (Twenty Eleven/Twelve/Thirteen) to see if your theme is the culprit.  It'll help narrow down the potential scope of your problem.

Comment: I'm pretty sure the theme is the culprit on Howl 2-Go, but idk about the blog... The thing is I don't have time to do a redesign. We're about to redesign the entire site over the winter so I just want to bring this site up to speed for the time being if I can. Check out these two PHP files, is there anything I can do about this: http://gtmetrix.com/reports/www.howlatthemoon.com/AP1EvOGE#report-timeline

Comment: sam as Pat, I see < 1 second loading time on both of those links. the 2nd has some javascript errors you should probably fix, but that's unrelated. do you see a difference if you're logged in versus not logged in? cacheing may be disabled for logged in visitors.

Answer (score 1):

your site is calling same file two times.

http://www.howlatthemoon.com/howl2go/wp-content/themes/cleanspace/js/core/theme.php?ver=3.5.2

you can see detail from here;

http://tools.pingdom.com/fpt/#!/cPOW4p/http://www.howlatthemoon.com/howl2go/

there are many error on second link;

http://tools.pingdom.com/fpt/#!/CyBhX/http://www.howlatthemoon.com/dueling_piano_bar/

Comment: Actually those are two different files. One is js and one is css. I am very aware of how slow they are but I have no idea how to correct that